# Folder structure for a Node.js project

Tags: node.js

I notice that Node.js projects often include folders like these:

> /libs, /vendor, /support, /spec, /tests

What exactly do these mean? What's the different between them, and where should I include referenced code?

Answer (score 494, accepted):

Concerning the folders you mentioned:

- **`/libs`** is usually used for custom `classes/functions/modules`
- **`/vendor`** or **`/support`** contains 3rd party libraries (added as git
  sub-module when using git as source control)
- **`/spec`** contains specifications for BDD tests.
- **`/tests`** contains the unit-tests for an application (using a testing
  framework, see
  [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-testing))

*NOTE: both `/vendor` and `/support` are deprecated since NPM introduced a clean package management. It's recommended to handle all 3rd-party dependencies using NPM and a package.json file*

When building a rather large application, I recommend the following additional folders (especially if you are using some kind of MVC- / ORM-Framework like [express](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master) or [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/)):

- **`/models`** contains all your ORM models (called `Schemas` in mongoose)
- **`/views`** contains your view-templates (using any templating language supported in express)
- **`/public`** contains all static content (images, style-sheets, client-side JavaScript)

  - **`/assets/images`** contains image files
  - **`/assets/pdf`** contains static pdf files
  - **`/css`** contains style sheets (or compiled output by a css engine)
  - **`/js`** contains client side JavaScript
- **`/controllers`** contain all your express routes, separated by module/area of your application (note: when using the bootstrapping functionality of express, this folder is called **`/routes`**)

I got used to organize my projects this way and i think it works out pretty well.

**Update for CoffeeScript-based Express applications (using [connect-assets](https://github.com/adunkman/connect-assets)):**

- **`/app`** contains your compiled JavaScript
- **`/assets/`** contains all client-side assets that require compilation

  - **`/assets/js`** contains your client-side CoffeeScript files
  - **`/assets/css`** contains all your LESS/Stylus style-sheets
- **`/public/(js|css|img)`** contains your static files that are not handled by any compilers
- **`/src`** contains all your server-side specific CoffeeScript files
- **`/test`** contains all unit testing scripts (implemented using a testing-framework of your choice)
- **`/views`** contains all your express views (be it jade, ejs or any other templating engine)

Comment: where would you put your client-side js,css,images?
would you suggest a similar folder structure in the public folder, like:

public/assets
public/assets/css
public/assets/images
public/assets/docs

public/libs
public/support
public/tests
public/models
public/views
public/controllers

?

Comment: expressjs creates a ./routes directory, is that the same as ./controllers in your example?

Comment: Why don't you create an Yeoman generator with that proposal? It could become a standard.

Comment: Question, aren't directory structures normally generated by the framework (i.e. Symfony for PHP)? With Express for example, no directory structure is created correct? developers are to manually create and maintain MVC design and routes ? I appreciate any feedback, I'm new to Express

Comment: @AnchovyLegend there is a generator framework called Yeoman which can be used for generating express-/angularjs based skeleton-apps (for example https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/tree/express-stack)

Comment: I´m using Webstorm. I think it generates projects with express. It generates an bin and routes folder

Comment: Isnt it much cleaner to have your tests close to your logic like
code.js and code.test.js in the same directory instead of a seperate test folder?

Comment: "`/libs` is usually used for custom classes/functions/modules" I'm not really sure about this convention. Sounds like, one would outsource regular classes, functions etc. to `lib` and reference them within `/src`. However, many people argue `lib` is for selected pieces of code that have been compiled and are ready to use code for users to consume. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39554555/9378384) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: When you say /spec contains specifications for BDD tests, do you mean e2e tests? Trying to understand how that differs from /test

Comment: Where would `html` reside?

Answer (score 58):

There is a discussion on GitHub because of a question similar to this one:
https://gist.github.com/1398757

You can use other projects for guidance, search in GitHub for:

- ThreeNodes.js - in my opinion, seems to have a specific structure not suitable for every project;
- lighter - an more simple structure, but lacks a bit of organization;

And finally, in a book (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025344.do) suggests this structure:

```
├── index.html
├── js/
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── models/
│   ├── views/
│   ├── collections/
│   ├── templates/
│   └── libs/
│       ├── backbone/
│       ├── underscore/
│       └── ...
├── css/
└── ...
```

Comment: I created a module to require files dynamically, allowing you to structure your project by feature rather than the typical Model, View, Controller.  Hope it helps someone:  https://github.com/ssmereka/crave

Answer (score 27):

More example from my project architecture you can see here:

```
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── config
│   └── production.json
├── package.json
├── schema
│   ├── create-db.sh
│   ├── db.sql
├── scripts
│   └── deploy-production.sh 
├── src
│   ├── app -> Containes API routes
│   ├── db -> DB Models (ORM)
│   └── server.js -> the Server initlializer.
└── test
```

Basically, the logical app separated to DB and APP folders inside the SRC dir.

Comment: if your app also contains a front end app do you put that under `src` or does the front end app get its own folder (with its own `package.json` and similar folder structure) ?

Comment: @wal I prefer to separate frontend projects to another repository as it's more organized

Answer (score 16):

Assuming we are talking about web applications and building APIs:

One approach is to **categorize files by feature**. To illustrate:

---

We are developing a library application. In the first version of the application, a user can:

- Search for books and see metadata of books
- Search for authors and see their books

In a second version, users can also:

- Create an account and log in
- Loan/borrow books

In a third version, users can also:

- Save a list of books they want to read/mark favorites

---

First we have the following structure:

```
books
  └─ entities
  │   └─ book.js
  │   └─ author.js
  │
  └─ services
  │   └─ booksService.js
  │   └─ authorsService.js
  │
  └─ repositories
  │   └─ booksRepository.js
  │   └─ authorsRepository.js
  │
  └─ controllers
  │   └─ booksController.js
  │   └─ authorsController.js
  │
  └─ tests
      └─ ...
```

We then add on the user and loan features:

```
user
  └─ controllers
  └─ entities
  └─ services
  └─ ...

loan
  └─ controllers
  └─ ...
```

And then the favorites functionality:

```
favorites
  └─ controllers
  └─ entities
  └─ ...
```

For any new developer that gets handed the task to add on that the books search should also return information if any book have been marked as favorite, it's really easy to see where in the code he/she should look.

Then when the product owner sweeps in and exclaims that the favorites feature should be removed completely, it's easy to remove it.

Comment: Where would you put database logic in such a structure? Since the database underpinning the repositories is presumably common to books and users, does this just end up having its own folder?

Comment: @castro I'd say the database connection is not specific to some feature. If you have one SQL database for example where most of your entities are stored, you could just store that logic in some src/db.js. If you have more than one data storage, then perhaps a src/infrastructure/ folder with logic for each storage would make sense.

Comment: Can also consider adopting the naming scheme of `books.repository.js`.

Comment: Although this has some benefits, there are drawbacks like the fact that common code across layers is awkward to place. For example, common plugins for your models, or middleware for your controllers. You end up having to hoist it all up to some common src folders which makes it harder to organize, instead of having it neatly kept in the respective layer folder.

Answer (score 4):

It's important to note that there's no consensus on what's the best approach and related frameworks in general do not enforce nor reward certain structures.

I find this to be a frustrating and huge overhead but equally important. It is sort of a downplayed version (but IMO more important) of the [style guide issue](https://www.codementor.io/mattgoldspink/nodejs-best-practices-du1086jja#5-use-a-style-guide). I like to point this out because the answer is the same: **it doesn't matter what structure you use as long as it's well defined and coherent**.

So I'd propose to look for a comprehensive guide that you like and make it clear that the project is based on this.

It's not easy, especially if you're new to this! Expect to spend hours researching. You'll find most guides recommending an MVC-like structure. While several years ago that might have been a solid choice, nowadays that's not necessarily the case. For example [here's another approach](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-node-js-project-structure-tutorial/).

Answer (score 2):

This is indirect answer, on the folder structure itself, very related.

A few years ago I had same question, took a folder structure but had to do a lot directory moving later on, because the folder was meant for a different purpose than that I have read on internet, that is, what a particular folder does has different meanings for different people on some folders.

Now, having done multiple projects, in addition to explanation in all other answers, on the folder structure itself, I would strongly suggest to follow the structure of Node.js itself, which can be seen at: https://github.com/nodejs/node. It has great detail on all, say linters and others, what file and folder structure they have and where. Some folders have a README that explains what is in that folder.

Starting in above structure is good because some day a new requirement comes in and but you will have a scope to improve as it is already followed by Node.js itself which is maintained over many years now.

Answer (score 0):

Just clone the repo from GitHub

https://github.com/abhinavkallungal/Express-Folder-Structure

This is a basic structure of a  node.js express.js project
with already setup  MongoDB as database, hbs as view engine, nodemon also,
so you can easily set up node js  express project

Step 1: download or clone the repo
Step 2: Open in any code editor
Step 3: Open the terminal on the folder path
Step 4: run the comment in terminal `npm start`
Step 5: start coding

Comment: Where do you state how controllers and business logic is managed?

Comment: nice directory structure.