# Confusing about path in node.js

Tags: node.js, path

I am new to Node.js and I have read the book "The Node Beginner Book" written by 'Manuel Kiessling'.

But there's something which this book does not cover that all the *.js* files are in the same folder or the same path.

e.g, when create a blog project and I named it blog, then I add the server.js, app.js.

Do I have to include the node.exe file in the same folder too? or Can I just place it else where?

Can anyone help or recommend some article about the path in Node.js.

Advance Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Folder structure for a nodejs project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178334/folder-structure-for-a-nodejs-project)  Also, you can put your files wherever you want.  There are recommended structures, but you are welcome to deviate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.exe should exist in the default location where it generally gets installed by default.

No need to include it in project or something like that.

Just you need to run your program like

```
node server.js
```

If it fails to run please verify the PATH env variable.

To do this,

Open command prompt

Then issue command `PATH`

Search for NODE variable and value

Cross check value i.e. the location, if it is wrong set it properly pointing to location where node.exe is installed, thats it...

Happy exploring...