# Node.js and Express.js Layout

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, express

Would this be an acceptable layout for my express application structure

**models**
Mongoose Models and Schemas for the Application

**views**
Jade template files

**routes**
Routing files

**controller**
Form Handling and API Handling (POST/JSON)

If this is not the best way to structure an application, what is, are there any examples?

Thanks.

Comment: I think routes and controllers do the same thing. I don't have controllers, only ./routes

Answer (score 3):

[Here's an example](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/mvc) directly from the Express code examples.

Likewise there's a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178334/) about this same topic.

Note that Express has several potential uses, so there's limited prescriptive guidance here.

Answer (score 2):

Try [express-orm-mvc](https://github.com/ddo/express-orm-mvc)
A simple package that support express and orm with mvc template