# What is a standard structure for NodeJs apps using MEANIO

Tags: node.js, mean.io

I found the following structure as kind of standard for nodejs programs from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178334/folder-structure-for-a-node-js-project):

```
- myApp
    - app.js
    - models
    - views
    - controllers(routes)
    - public
```

But when I create my own custom package in nodejs via "mean package myApp". The meanio will create a slightly different structure:

```
- myApp
    -app.js
    - server
        - models
        - views
        - controllers
        - routes
        - config
    - public
```

in which app.js is not located in the same dir as models and routes.
Is there any significant difference between these two structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directory structure is nothing but the matter of preference, you can use any directory structure of your choice. There is nothing like a standard structure for NodeJs apps.
If MeanIO create  such a directory structure for you, you should probably go with it, unless you prefer some other structure.

Comment: Thanks Naeem. So, It means it is not necessary that app.js be in the same folder as other files. Am I right?