# How to organize folder structure in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm searching for  a video/blog post or something related that help me organize my node.js web application.

I have an application where i am using express.js upon node.js.

I'm using:

```
Mvc pattern, 
i18n, 
config env prod/dev, 
custom middlewares, 
custom prototypes
custom modules
```

I need organize better the folder structure, but i don't know exactly how.

I already search for this, but i was only able to find poor explanations about an good folder structure in a node.js app.

The app also have an admin dashboard, so i am separating the public, views and controllers like this:

```
public
|-- admin
|-- client
views
|-- admin
|-- client
controllers
|-- admin
|-- client
```

This is a good idea?

Anyone knows a good book, video or blog post that can help me with my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a pretty solid [thread on Node App structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178334/folder-structure-for-a-node-js-project).

In my own opinion, I always try to follow the rule of never repeating yourself in development. Looks like you are  repeating your structure a lot above. If I were you I would do one of the following:

1. Make two separate Node apps. One for clients and one for admin.
2. If your controllers are going to be similar for both client or admin, I would consider building one app that identifies a user as a general user or an admin and render their experience that way. Then just throw away the admin/client folders.

**EDIT:**

Scotch.io always has great articles on Node and Express. See if [this article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/node-and-angular-to-do-app-application-organization-and-structure) or their other articles help.

**Best Answer:**

After some team research we found [this link](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/1398757) to be most useful. It has a great five folder layout for an admin panel and client experience.

Comment: my controllers in the admin/client have the same name, but the logic is totally different, that's why i separate in two different folders :B.

Comment: @DRX I mean if that is the case, why not just create to different Node apps? It would be more organized, faster and probably safer.

Comment: separating in two different apps is a good alternative for large applications i think, in my case is not necessary unfortunate =(..

Comment: You mean you aren't building Facebook? :P I mean still, it would be more organized and probably easier to read.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/1398757 what you think about the 5: Top-level /client and /server directories ??

Comment: Yeah this is probably the best you are going to get. I am going to save this. See where he/she has their views folder? You should follow that pattern. Admin also in helpers. This looks like what you were looking for.

Comment: thanks for your help @MaxBaldwin :). I am going to use the 5 pattern.

Comment: @DRX awesome! And good luck. I am going to add that link to my answer.