# Meaning of lib directory in github repositories

Tags: javascript, github, directory, conventions

Most of the time, when I look at projects in github , I see lib/ directory.

I just googled if there is a conventional meaning of lib/ directory. But I couldn't find much.

I would like to know what lib/ directory is for just to choose where to start looking at in github projects.

Project which have lib/ directories.

[orchestrator](https://github.com/robrich/orchestrator)

[gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp)

Comment: You got an example? I know various applications and projects having a lib directory, but the meaning is different for most of them.

Comment: I added an example I was just trying to understand.

Comment: Oo, I thought maybe it has a general meaning.

Comment: Not very general, but in your case it seems you look at a lot of JS code. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178334/folder-structure-for-a-node-js-project). It seems to be very popular in node.js and co.

Comment: `lib` is short for `library` which is often used for common files, utility classes, imported dependencies, or 'back in the days' also for dlls for (desktop) applications. It's in general a 'library' of supporting code for the core application. But there is no rule (not that I know of, at least) that says you should have a lib, or that its name is 'lib', or what to put in it.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `lib` directory, for most of my projects, is where I place shared components that might be used in multiple facets of my application. Things in this folder should *not* be tightly coupled to your application, and should theoretically be able to be plucked from one project to another, and work as expected (assuming all dependencies are available). Some examples of things I put in my `lib` folders:

- If I'm defining a policy/process for loading bootstrapped data off the page into my frontend code, I would define the class/method in a file in the `lib` folder. It is just functional, and not bound to any of my application code or DOM structure.
- If I need to build my own UI components (let's say I need to merge some Tagging functionality into a text area, and am unhappy with existing OSS alternatives), I would do it here. The code in `lib` just outlines *how* my component works, but doesn't implement any application-specific functionality. I can then include this in my core application and use it as if it were a third party library.

Essentially, anything that *could* be a third party dependency that you don't want to place in it's own repository and set up management for, you can use `lib` and have that functionality cleanly decoupled within your primary app.

Comment: Quick note that for actual third-party dependencies, I use the package manager prescribed location (e.g. `node_modules`) when available, or a `vendor` directory.

Comment: would you hence add lib into `.gitignore`?

Comment: No, because your application requires that code to operate, and it can't be installed by any other means (i.e. it's not provided by a vendor or package manager). If you were to clone the repository on a new computer, you need to also pull the contents of `lib` for it to run.

Comment: if I have in `lib` third parties modules, normally I fetch them during build

Comment: `lib` is not typically for storing third party dependencies, those are usually handled by a package manager (e.g. `npm` installing dependencies into `node_modules`), and if you are manually pulling third party dependencies, standard practice is to put them in a `vendor` directory. `lib` is typically for code that is written as a part of your application, but is not tightly coupled to the business logic of your application directly.

Comment: npm has the default node_modules directory for third party dependencies, but they are to be used by the backend. I meant in the frontend upon building the dist directory. Where shall I put third party libs if I want to store these files in my server?