# Difference between lib and dist folders when packaging library using webpack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

Ive just published my first package (a react component) to npm but im having some trouble understanding the difference between what the `lib` directory is compared to the `dist`.

Currently I generate both `lib` and `dist` however my package "main" points to the `dist` unminified js file which has been built using webpack and output as UMD. The lib folder is built using `babel` taking the `src` and outputting to `lib`.

The dist folder contains both [unminified/minified].js files as well as [unminified/minified].css files.

My main confusion is with the lib folder since imports from there currently wouldn't work seeing as I just transform `src -> lib` meaning the scss references are still there and the scss files aren't transformed either.

I use CSS Modules (css-loader, styles-loader, postcss-loader etc) to generate my CSS files and this is where the confusion is since, wouldn't I also need to use webpack to generate my `lib` folder seeing as the `scss` files/import references need to be transformed to `css`?

**Are you meant to have both lib and dist or is the UMD build in dist fulling the same purpose as that of having a lib folder?**

**If you are supposed to have both how would I achieve this, since I couldnt find any info regarding generating the lib folder when using CSS modules within your js files and still maintaing the same folder structure of that of src (while still generating dist)?**

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Usually the `dist` folder is for shipping a UMD that a user can use if they aren't using package management. The `lib` folder is what `package.json` `main` points to, and users that install your package using `npm` will consume that directly. The only use of the `lib` as opposed to `src` is to transform your source using babel and webpack to be more generally compatible, since most build processes don't run babel transforms on packages in `node_modules`.

As far as handling the style imports, it's probably a good idea to not import scss or css files in your source js that you export. This is because node can't import styles like that by default. If you have an example that demos your component, it makes sense to import the styles there. The common pattern is to publish minified and unminified css in the `dist` folder, and in your documentation tell the consumer to explicitly import the css file using whatever technique they prefer. I took this approach with [redux bug reporter](https://github.com/dtschust/redux-bug-reporter#2-render-ui-component) if you need an example. Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok cool thanks for that, I understand the difference better now. However, this is the small library i just published https://github.com/deep-c/react-redux-notify/ and as you can see i bind classNames to the component which i import from its associated scss stylesheet which is tranformed via css-loader, style-loader, sass-loader and then added to my components default props.

Comment: I'd appreciated an answer that doesn't require me to lookup [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) for the umpteenth time ;).

Answer (score 3):

In general `lib` refers to libraries that are included in a package, `dist` on the other hand are distribution files for your project. As an example you could write a bunch of javascript and include jquery (which is a lib) and then when they're all bundled up you have a single dist file.

Answer (score 1):

Ok think I found out how to do this. There is a babel plugin that allows you to use webpack loaders when running babel ([babel-plugin-webpack-loaders](https://github.com/istarkov/babel-plugin-webpack-loaders)). Thus my CSS mapping is inlined within the js file and the mapping hashes used are also the same as that used when building dist. Yay!

Comment: Question: what diff between "lib" and "dist", answer: "I found out how to do this" ???