# How do I properly modulate my code in a Node.JS project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

[TL;DR] Just read the bits in **bold**.

I'm pretty new to Node.JS but have been getting on fine building some working projects. Now I have a burning question that I have been Googling for about half an hour but all I can find is frustratingly *light-touch* tutorials that don't answer my question, so here I go...

**I have a Node.JS project** that uses the Express framework. **The code for one of the routes is getting pretty big now,** so naturally my instincts as a good programmer are to break it out into it's own Class or Module or Package or whatever it is to be called....  and here lies my problem. Where is the tutorial about the *language* around Node.JS and **how does one go about carving up their own code into neatly modulated, easy-to-read chunks?**

It seems that every guide out there goes like this...

1. Create a NodeJS project
2. Install an npm module to the project
3. Add a single line route that calls the module
4. Pat yourself on the back and start applying for jobs as a full-stack JavaScript developer.

It's doing my head in! I wanna get deep and dirty with some complicated bespoke code but I also want to do things in some proper, standardised way but I don't know what folders to create, how to nest them, what naming convention to follow or anything like that. Where's the Jeff Way for NodeJS?

Please, someone **point me in the direction of a good tutorial** or some documentation around this subject so I can continue my learning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What i usually do is is put my logic in controllers and reference them from the routes.js. e.g.: personController with a method findPerson(id) and then in the routes.js put a route router.get('/:id', personController.findPerson)

Comment: @programmingheadaches Cool. That's the kind of thing I'm after. So just a folder called "controllers" in the root of the project yeah?

Comment: yeah just put a folder controllers in the root

Answer (score 0):

From the section headed **"Code Organization"** on [An Absolute Beginner's Guide to Node.JS](https://blog.xervo.io/absolute-beginners-guide-to-nodejs):

> In most applications your code will be split into several files. There's no standard or enforced organization to what files go where. This isn't Rails. There's no concept of views go here and controllers go there. You can do whatever you want.

So there have it. This isn't Rails  You can do whatever you want

But looking at the accepted answer to another question on SO: [Folder structure for a Node.js project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178334/folder-structure-for-a-node-js-project#5193206) we can see that a folder called **`controllers`** in the root of the project is a common location but also that the **`routes`** folder created when you use the [Express Generator](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) to bootstrap a new project is considered an alternative to this.

**Summary: All things considered and inspired by both my experience using other MVC frameworks (eg. Laravel) and [@programmingheadache's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42162441/how-do-i-properly-modulate-my-code-in-a-node-js-project#42162997) I am going to keep the `routes` folder but also create a `controllers` folder as well.**

This way I can keep the **`routes`** folder specifically for defining the routing of the project and keep the logic separate in several files inside **`controllers`** . I follow the mantra that *routing is documentation* and I would hate for any future reviewers of my project to get bogged-down by logic when they are just trying to establish the early basics of what URIs exist and with what parameters.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is is put my logic in controllers and reference them from the routes.js. e.g.: personController with a method find(id) and then in the routes.js put a route

```
router.get('/:id', personController.find);
```

personcontroller:

```
module.exports = (app) => {
  return { 
      find(req, res, next){
          const id = req.params.id
          //return a user
      } 
  };
}
```

routes:

```
router.get('/:id', personController.find);
```

pass every error to next and use a middleware to handle them

greetings

Ian

Comment: Your comment on the OP was helpful but the example in this answer seems a little too specific to your own project and I am worried it might be confusing to future readers. Would you be offended if I edited the answer to just cover the question of a good naming convention?

Comment: sure, go ahead! i don't find it too specific and it isn't a snippet from my own project. I'll edit my response a bit

Answer (score 0):

For the

> Please, someone point me in the direction of a good tutorial or some
> documentation around this subject so I can continue my learning.
> Thanks in advance.

part:

```
├───models
│   ├───user.model.js
├───routes
│   ├───user.route.js
├───services
│   ├───user.service.js
├───controllers
│   ├───user.controller.js
```

from https://riptutorial.com/node-js/example/32331/model-routes-controllers-services-directory-structure

and

```
src
│   app.js          # App entry point
└───api             # Express route controllers for all the endpoints of the app
└───config          # Environment variables and configuration related stuff
└───jobs            # Jobs definitions for agenda.js
└───loaders         # Split the startup process into modules
└───models          # Database models
└───services        # All the business logic is here
└───subscribers     # Event handlers for async task
└───types           # Type declaration files (d.ts) for Typescript
```

from https://softwareontheroad.com/ideal-nodejs-project-structure/

Comment: I've just realized that i've answered a post from 2017 that somehow got fresh in the `javascript` tag. Anyway I hope this is useful for someone (OP for sure would have figured out what works the best for him quite some time ago...)

Answer (score -1):

Project structure must be like :

```
-- app.js
-- server.js
```

config \

```
--databaseConfig.js

--thirdPartyConfig.js

--appConfig.js
```

controllers \

```
--userCtrl.js

--productCtrl.js

--businessCtrl.js
```

middlewares \

```
--endpointHandler.js

--authHandler.js

--errorHandler.js
```

routes \

```
--userRoute.js

--productRoute.js

--businessRoute.js
```

utils \

```
--encryptFile.js

--uploadFile.js
```

Comment: Why do you say _must_ when it absolutely isn't a _must_?